# grey out a textbox until enabled by checkbox

Tags: powershell, checkbox, textbox

I'm creating a script and I want the user to mark certain checkboxes to enable txtboxes.

When the user presses the chexbox, the textbox next to it will be enabled. If they don't, then they cannot insert text into it.

Right now it doesn't work, has someone an idea how to change it?
Thanks for your help!

Here is the part of my script with the checkbox and the textbox:

```
#creating the whole form
 $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
 $objForm.Text = "Ofir`s script"
 $objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(480,240) 
 $objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"


 #This creates the TextBox1
 $objTextBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
 $objTextBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,40) 
 $objTextBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,150)
 $objTextBox1.TabIndex = 3 
 $objTextBox1.text = Dsp.z
 $objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox1)

 #This creates a checkbox for textbox1
 $objDsp2Checkbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox 
 $objDsp2Checkbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,40) 
 $objDsp2Checkbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
 $objDsp2Checkbox.TabIndex = 0
 $objForm.Controls.Add($objDsp2Checkbox)

#changing the file name
if ($objDsp2Checkbox.Checked -eq $true)
{
$objTextBox1.Enabled = $true  
}

elseif ($objDsp2Checkbox.Checked -eq $false)
{
$objTextBox1.Enabled = $false
}    


 #makes the form appear on top of the screen
 $objForm.Topmost = $True

 $objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
 [void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: [I wrote some code that doesn't work: \*splotch\*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some guides for what to do to work out why, but also what to ask to make a more specific and answerable question. (Not all applicable to Powershell, I acknowledge)

Comment: thanks, i see your point. im new to this website and to powershell so i dont really know what i am doing wrong here. tried to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the bit of code that enables/disables the text box to an event handler on the checkbox object. Most likely the Click event.

```
$objDsp2Checkbox_OnClick = {
    if ($objDsp2Checkbox.Checked -eq $true)
    {
        $objTextBox1.Enabled = $true  
    }
    elseif ($objDsp2Checkbox.Checked -eq $false)
    {
        $objTextBox1.Enabled = $false
    }   
}
$objDsp2Checkbox.Add_Click($objDsp2Checkbox_OnClick)
```

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25911.how-to-add-a-powershell-gui-event-handler-part-1.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `$objTextBox1.Enabled = $objDsp2Checkbox.Checked` no need for if/else